# Lisp performance optimal solution in string processing

Tags: string, performance, lisp, common-lisp

I have a string with underscores separating words (e.g. **aaa_bbb_ccc**)

I created a function to covert the string to camelCase (e.g. **aaaBbbCcc**).

I am wondering if there are some things that I am doing wrong which affect the performance. This is the code:

```
(defun underscore-to-camel (input)
        (defparameter input-clean-capitalized (remove #\_ (string-capitalize input)))
        (setf (aref input-clean-capitalized 0) (aref (string-downcase (aref input-clean-capitalized 0)) 0))
        input-clean-capitalized)
```

I also created a second variant but it is ~25% slower (measured 3 million executions using `time`):

```
(defun underscore-to-camel-v2 (input)
        (defparameter input-clean-capitalized (remove #\_ (string-capitalize input)))
        (concatenate 
            'string 
            (string-downcase (aref input-clean-capitalized 0)) 
            (subseq input-clean-capitalized 1)))
```

Comment: Why not simply use a regexp replace of `\([a-z]\)_\([a-z]\)` with `\1\,(upcase \2)`?

Comment: I am using lispbox (Clozure Common Lisp). Regular expressions are not available by default. Which library you suggest that support `upcase`?

Comment: You might want to properly indent the code. Then `defparameter` is not used that way. `defparameter` is for global functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of, defparameter is not what you want to use. You should really refactor
your code like this:

```
(defun underscore-to-camel (input)
  (let ((input-clean-capitalized (remove #\_ (string-capitalize input))))
    (setf (aref input-clean-capitalized 0)
          (aref (string-downcase (aref input-clean-capitalized 0)) 0))
    input-clean-capitalized))
```

Second: You could approach the problem like this:

```
(defun underscore-to-camel-eff (input)
  (declare (optimize (debug 1) (speed 3) (safety 1)))
  (loop :with length = (length input)
        :with i = 0
        :while (< i length)
        :for c = (aref input i)
        :if (or (= i (- length 1))
                (char/= c #\_))
        :collect (prog1 c (incf i)) :into result
        :else
        :collect (prog1
                   (char-upcase (aref input (+ i 1)))
                   (incf i 2))
        :into result
        :finally (return (concatenate 'string result))))
```

which runs, on my PC with SBCL, in half the time of your solution.

And here's a solution using regular expression, albeit slower than any of the other solutions:

```
(defun underscore-to-camel-ppcre (input)
  (declare (optimize (debug 1) (speed 3) (safety 1)))
  (ppcre:regex-replace-all "_([a-z])"
                           input
                           (lambda (target-string
                                    start
                                    end
                                    match-start
                                    match-end
                                    reg-starts
                                    reg-ends)
                             (declare (ignore start
                                              end
                                              match-end
                                              reg-starts
                                              reg-ends))
                             (string
                              (char-upcase
                               (aref target-string (+ 1 match-start)))))))
```

The necessary package is called "ppcre".
You can install it via

```
(ql:quickload "cl-ppcre")
```

Once you went to http://www.quicklisp.org/beta/ and installed quicklisp.

Answer (score 2):

I would propose to use character-level functions. They start with `char-`. Then you can get rid of `STRING-DOWNCASE` and "CONCATENATE`.

`DEFPARAMETER` is not used for local variables. Use `LET`.

But a simple version is this:

```
(defun underscore-to-camel (input)
  (string-downcase (remove #\_ (string-capitalize input))
                   :start 0
                   :end 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

One more way to do it:

```
(defun underscore-to-camel (input)
  (with-output-to-string (s)
    (loop
       :for c :across input
       :for upcase := (char= c #\_) :then (or upcase (char= c #\_)) :do
       (cond
         ((char= c #\_))
         (upcase (write-char (char-upcase c) s) (setf upcase nil))
         (t (write-char c s))))))
```

Answer (score 2):

After experimenting a while with SBCL this is the fastest version I found

```
(defun camelcase (s)
  (do* ((n (length s))
        (i 0 (the fixnum (1+ i)))
        (wp 0)
        (target (make-array n :element-type 'character)))
      ((>= i n) (subseq target 0 wp))
    (declare (fixnum n i wp)
             (string s))
    (if (and (< i (the fixnum (1- n)))
             (char= (char s i) #\_)
             (char>= (char s (the fixnum (1+ i))) #\a)
             (char<= (char s (the fixnum (1+ i))) #\z))
        (setf (aref target (1- (the fixnum (incf wp))))
              (code-char (- (char-code (char s (the fixnum (incf i)))) 32)))
        (setf (aref target (1- (the fixnum (incf wp))))
              (char s i)))))
```

Instead of calling `#'char-upcase` I'm just subtracting 32 because the character is known to be in the `a`-`z` range and I'm supposing ASCII encoding. This shaves off some cycle.

Also for some reason I don't understand explicit array filling is faster than using `vector-push`.